# Upload file to Contabo Object Storage (S3 compatible)

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core

I'm trying to upload a file to the contabo object storage from memory stream using AWSSDK.S3

This is my client configuration.

```
    string accessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config config = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config();
    Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client s3Client;


    public BookingsController()
    {
        config.ServiceURL = "https://eu2.contabostorage.com";
        config.DisableHostPrefixInjection = true;

        s3Client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(
                accessKey,
                secretKey,
                config
                );

    }
```

This is the method I'm using:

```
    [HttpPost("/api/Bookings/AddFile")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddBookingFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        using (var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ListBucketsResponse response = await s3Client.ListBucketsAsync();

            file.CopyTo(newMemoryStream);

            Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest request = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = "test-bucket";
            request.Key = "recording.wav";
            request.ContentType = "audio/wav";
            request.InputStream = newMemoryStream;
            await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);

        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

The ListBucket-Method works properly. The PutObject Method throws the exception that the Host "Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt. (test-bucket.eu2.contabostorage.com:443)" cannot be found.

Referenced to the Contabo-docs is that correct, because Contabo doesn't support virtual hosted buckets (dns prefix). [Reference to contabo docs](https://docs.contabo.com/docs/products/Object-Storage/technical-description)

I thought, that the following configuration fix this, but that wasn't the solution.

```
config.DisableHostPrefixInjection = true;
```

Does anyone has any advise hot to prevent the prefixing of the url?

Comment: Use `ForcePathStyle` to force path style endpoints

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost("upload_file")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        string url = "";

        try
        {
            var accessKey = "xxxx";
            var secretKey = "xxxx";
            var bucketName = "xxxx";

            AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
            config.ServiceURL = "https://eu2.contabostorage.com";
            config.DisableHostPrefixInjection = true;
            config.ForcePathStyle = true;

            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                    accessKey,
                    secretKey,
                    config
                    );

            ListBucketsResponse response = await s3Client.ListBucketsAsync();

            using (var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(newMemoryStream);
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
                request.BucketName = bucketName;
                request.Key = file.FileName;
                request.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                request.InputStream = newMemoryStream;
                await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);

                GetPreSignedUrlRequest requestGet = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
                requestGet.BucketName = bucketName;
                requestGet.Key = file.FileName;
                requestGet.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
                requestGet.Protocol = Protocol.HTTPS;
                url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(requestGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, Utils.errorMessage(ex));
        }
        return Ok(url);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Camilo, some explanation on the code solves the issue is always welcome. Even when it looks simple